# Research on TDD

Tags: tdd

I know there is done some research on TDD at the North Carolina State University. They have published a paper called '[An Initial Investigation of Test Driven Development in Industry](http://collaboration.csc.ncsu.edu/laurie/Papers/TDDpaperv8.pdf)'. Other publications by NCSU can be found [here](http://collaboration.csc.ncsu.edu/laurie/publications.html).

Can anybody point me to other good publications on this topic?

Comment: In the article posted, it mentions that it took 16% longer to complete a project with TDD. While they did mention the tests as a byproduct of the process, they didn't seem to focus on the fact that at the end of TDD, you have code AND tests.IMO the tests more than pay for themselves in the long run

Comment: can you reconsider my answer as the answer since WeDoTDD.com is fresh data and proof that TDD works and how it's worked for companies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[On the Effectiveness of the Test-First Approach to Programming](http://www.cs.du.edu/~snarayan/sada/teaching/COMP3705/lecture/p1/NRC-47445.pdf), by Hakan Erdogmus, Maurizio Morisio, and Marco Torchiano.

Despite the name it covers TDD:

Abstract:

> Test-Driven Development (TDD) is based
>   on formalizing a piece of
>   functionality as a test, implementing
>   the functionality such that the test
>   passes, and iterating the process.
>
> This paper describes a controlled
>   experiment for evaluating an important
>   aspect of TDD: In TDD, programmers
>   write functional tests before the
>   corresponding implementation code. The
>   experiment was conducted with
>   undergraduate students. While the
>   experiment group applied a test-first
>   strategy, the control group applied a
>   more conventional development
>   technique, writing tests after the
>   implementation. Both groups followed
>   an incremental process, adding new
>   features one at a time and regression
>   testing them.
>
> We found that test-first
>   students on average wrote more tests
>   and, in turn, students who wrote more
>   tests tended to be more productive. We
>   also observed that the minimum quality
>   increased linearly with the number of
>   programmer tests, independent of the
>   development strategy employed.

Comment: Wow.. 404. That's some sharp irony.

Answer (score 4):

The [ACM Digital Library](http://portal.acm.org/dl.cfm) has quite a few papers on TDD.  Simply Search for Test Driven Development.

The top results from Google's [Test driven development academic research](http://www.google.com/search?q=test+driven+development+academic+research):

[Test-Driven Development: Concepts, Taxonomy, and Future Direction](http://www2.computer.org/portal/web/csdl/doi/10.1109/MC.2005.314) in the IEEE Computer Society.

[software Architecture Improvement through TDD](http://www.acm.org/src/subpages/gf_entries_06/DavidJanzen_src_gf06.pdf) at the ACM

Answer (score 0):

As a TDD Practitioner myself, I have launched a new site [WeDoTDD.com](http://WeDoTDD.com) that lists just that.  Companies practicing it, and stories behind how they practice Test Driven Development!